# Angular X-editable set focus event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, x-editable

I'm using [angular-xeditable](http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#editable-table) api.Could you tell me how to setfocus into a control when form 'loads' and press 'add row' button ?

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sampath_lokuge/NfPcH/13181/)

There is a method named `$activate(name)` on the above api.But I don't know how to use it with the above scenarios.Thanks.

```
 // add user
  $scope.addUser = function() {
    $scope.users.push({
      id: $scope.users.length+1,
      name: '',
      status: null,
      group: null,
      isNew: true
    });
  };
```

[image: pic]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ckosloski/dkey68by/47/) with what I came up with to fix your problem.

I added a setFocus function call in the addUser method

```
    $timeout( function() { 
        $scope.setFocus('name', $scope.users.length - 1); 
    }, 50);

    $scope.setFocus = function (id, index) {
        angular.element( document.querySelectorAll("#" + id))[index].focus(); 
    };
```